# How to send the signalr messages as Json format instead of binary format

Tags: signalr-hub, blazor-server-side

I have a Sever Side Blazor application in .NET Core 3.1.5 and I added support for the SignalR.  Then  I created a signal r hub class and the razor components can interact with the hub fine.

My intention is to be able to see the websocket messages under the browser Network tab in Json format, and not in binary format as it is now.

In the Startup classs I did not specified any binary format or protocol.  I thought that by default it will be Json format.

How can I see the websockets messages in Json format?

Answer (score -2):

YOU COULD USE MessagePack Hub Protocol in SignalR for ASP.NET Core HERE IS A LINK TO READ MORE IT MAY HELP YOY:=

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/messagepackhubprotocol?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Hi Ghaith,  I tried adding the MessagePack protocol with the document however I got the following error in the startup class:   MissingFieldException: Field not found: 'MessagePack.Resolvers.DynamicEnumAsStringResolver.Instance'.